# onClick listener and onClick on XML won't work

Tags: java, android, button, onclick, crash

So I ran into a problem while trying to make a login/register with sharedPreferences, if I have the onCick inside of the onCreate method with a onCickListener the method won't run, and if I have the method outside the onCreate with the method call on the XML it will crash.

Full java code with onClickListener:

```
package com.example.mrsanchez.tunalogs;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Region;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class register extends AppCompatActivity {
    //
    //Variables:
    //
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
    public static final String name = "nameKey";
    public static final String email = "emailKey";
    public static final String password = "passwordKey";
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    EditText edName;
    EditText edPassword;
    EditText edRepeat;
    EditText edEmail;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        edName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
        edPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
        edRepeat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtRepeat);
        edEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
        Button regist = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegisterFinal);

        regist.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String n = edName.getText().toString();
                String p = edPassword.getText().toString();
                String pr = edRepeat.getText().toString();
                String e = edEmail.getText().toString();

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

                if(p.equals(pr))
                {
                    editor.putString(name, n);
                    editor.putString(password, p);
                    editor.putString(email, e);
                    editor.commit();
                    Toast.makeText(register.this,"Your account has been successfully created!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(register.this, "Your passwords do not correspond.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Full XML code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_register"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.mrsanchez.tunalogs.register">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:hint="Username"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtUsername"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtRepeat"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtPassword"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:hint="Confirm Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtRepeat"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:hint="E-Mail"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRegisterFinal"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtEmail"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Register"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Current logcat(No crashes, but method still not running):

```
10-18 14:44:48.681 16037-16037/? E/cutils: to chown(/mnt/shell/emulated/0, 0, 0)
10-18 14:44:48.681 16037-16037/? E/cutils: to chown(/mnt/shell/emulated/obb, 0, 0)
10-18 14:44:48.682 16037-16037/? E/cutils: to chown(/storage/emulated/0/Android, 0, 0)
10-18 14:44:48.682 16037-16037/? E/cutils: to chown(/storage/emulated/0/Android/obb, 0, 0)
10-18 14:44:48.804 16037-16037/com.example.mrsanchez.tunalogs E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.monkeyPatchExistingResources
10-18 14:44:48.809 16037-16037/com.example.mrsanchez.tunalogs E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.pruneResourceCache
10-18 14:44:48.912 16037-16037/com.example.mrsanchez.tunalogs E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
```

Please help me, I've been roaming around stack overflow for a while and haven't really found anything that worked, unless I overloocked or missed something.

Comment: Please post logcat?

Comment: Sorry I knew Iwas forgeting something, 1 second.

Comment: how about toasts in first case , is any one appearing ?

Comment: @PavneetSingh Negative.

Comment: Computer battery just died on me and I have no charger with me, I'll have to fetch on somewhere really quick and the I'll post the log at, I was mid way trough it D:

Comment: @MrSanchez Can you click on the button 4 or more times, and can you let me know if you are able to get any Toast?

Comment: @superman at the moment the version I have on my phone has the second method(onClick call directly ob XML) so it just simply crashes, I will post logcar as soon as I get battery on my pc

Comment: please post your logcat

Comment: @AbhayBohra aye, I will, I was mid way trough it but ny computer's battery died has I said above, and dont currently have a charger on me, I will post it has soon has I have the computer charging.

Comment: Added logcat, logcat is referent to the 2nd method.

Comment: @MrSanchez Please post xml referenced to 2nd java snippet

Comment: @Raghavendra the xml is exactly the same, the difference is that I have `android:onCick="regist";` on the button code.

Comment: @MrSanchez just for confirmation did u copy this line android:onCick="regist" now from that xml or you have typed this? Because the log says it couldn't find that method so.

Comment: @MrSanchez you have typed, this there is no android:onCick its onClick. Please copy that line from xml or post that button code from layout

Comment: @Raghavendra aye that was a mistake, gonna update the OP 1 sec.

Comment: @MrSanchez Did u use activity_register.xml in any other activity?

Comment: @MrSanchez can u tell me what is the file name of that xml?

Comment: @MrSanchez small hunch remove android:id="@+id/activity_register" from relative layout and try

Comment: @Raghavendra if I do that I won't have any way to call it from the main activity

Comment: @MrSanchez what is the file name by the way?

Comment: @MrSanchez In this setContentView(R.layout.activity_register); activity_register is not the file name then???

Comment: that's the ID, file name is register.java and activity_register.xml, android adds the "activity_" automatically

Comment: seems like everything is ok ,you can try clear and then run

Comment: @PavneetSingh can we try something? I send you the whole code of the app, including the main activity, and maybe you try to run it to see if the problem is on my side?

Comment: i can't , don't have the android studio around but seems like the problem is somewhere else in your project  which is this `Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable'`

Comment: That's what's wierd, it doesn't crash with it, it just says it in the logcat but nothing actually happans, I might try to just remake the project.

Comment: @PavneetSingh solved the problem, thanks for your help, I posted the answer here so just in case you ever run into something like this or you see someone else with this problem, then remind yourself of this thread ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up finding out the answer.

The first time I tried to do this I missed out on one thing: On my Main activity I was calling the second activity with

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
```

This caused all buttons and other controls to not function like they should, so you should do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(login.this, register.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:onClick="regist"` on button in xml layout.

Comment: Aye, I did, forgot to mention.

Comment: @MrSanchez you did not. We can see your code and it's not there.

Comment: The first XML I gave was for the method with a onClick listener, hence I didn't need to have it set on the XML (I don't think I do at least), but on the second method I have it.

Comment: @TimCastelijns but OP said if he tried both cases but maybe showed code for first case only)

Comment: @Akash tried that yesterday, for some reason it actually didn't work, some wierd stuff on happening on this app :P